# Where do I place common logic required in multiple classes implementing the same interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Given the following interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool Foo(Person a, Person b);
}
```

and the following two implementations of the above:

```
public class KungFoo : IFoo
{
    public bool Foo(Person a, Person b)
    {
        if (a.IsAmateur || b.IsAmateur) // common logic
          return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public class KongFoo : IFoo
{
    public bool Foo(Person a, Person b)
    {
        if (a.IsAmateur || b.IsAmateur) // common logic
          return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

where should I place the "common logic" (as commented in the code) so it is in just one place (e.g. as a Func) and does not need to be repeated (as is the case above) for multiple implementations?

*Note that the example above is very trivial but the real-life "common logic" is more complicated and the Foo() method does something useful!*

I hope the question is clear (and not already been answered elsewhere - I did do a search) but feel free to probe me for more details if required.

Comment: Looks like there's a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343923/where-to-put-common-interface-methods-when-dealing-with-partial-classes-inherit - only saw it in the Related section after I posted this one! Although mine is when two methods do different things but have common logic embedded within them...

Comment: It's a bit unclear what specifically you're deeming common logic here.  You're indicating a line of code that doesn't refer to the properties of the class at all so it could just be factored out into a static method in some utility class.  If your common code uses the class members you may be able to use an extension method, but only if these members are exposed by the interface. Finally you could use a base class.  But the 'right' answer depends somewhat on the specifics of the common logic.

Comment: @James: thanks for your comment. Sorry, my mistake: I made the common logic too simplistic but a and b are objects of two different types/classes which do not belong to the implementation classes. So, based on your comment, it should probably be placed in a static method in a utility class.

Comment: If the logic doesn't reference any members then essentially it is a static method, so I'd make it one.  You could still put it in a common base class if you like that design, but this restricts your ability to construct implementations of your interface derived from other base classes.  So personally I'd choose a separate internal utility class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a common abstract class:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool Foo(Person a, Person b);
}

public abstract class FooBase : IFoo
{
    public virtual bool Foo(Person a, Person b)
    {
        if (a.IsAmateur || b.IsAmateur) // common logic
          return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public class KungFoo : FooBase
{

}

public class KongFoo : FooBase
{
    public override bool Foo(Person a, Person b)
    {
        // Some other logic if the common logic doesn't work for you here
    }
}
```

Comment: It's personal preference of course, but seeing a class named with the 'I' prefix which is usually reserved for interfaces just seems wrong to me. I like the abstract class idea but I'd drop the 'I'.

Comment: Isn't it better to not call the abstract class `IFooBase` but just `FooBase` ?

Comment: @JamesGaunt: No you're absolutely correct. If I caught one of my junior developers doing that I'd kick them in the pants. I was typing quickly to get the answer out. I'll change it in an edit shortly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Joel. I think I now know how to go about implementation my solution.

Comment: PS. Unfortunately, I can't upvote because I'm not a fully-fledged user yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use base classes for common methods, but your common logic (or business rule) can be externalised rather neatly using the **Specification Pattern**.

There's lots of wordy examples and white papers out there, read through them if you're okay with that sort of stuff (I find it a bit too academic orientated), but there does seem a good introduction at:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/jeff_perrin/archive/2006/12/13/the-specification-pattern.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the Specification Pattern, Adrian. I'm reading up on it right now.

Answer (score 0):

- You could implement a class that is inherited by all appropriate classes and provides the functionality as a `protected` method.
- Preferably you might implement an **Extension Method**, which I would prefer because it does not restrict you to use this logic in a certain inheritance hierarchy but instead allows you to use it in all classes that share the type or interface.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @Jens. I ought to have given a more realistic example of the common logic (in that the parameters are of different types) so implementing an extension method would prove difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an abstract base class like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool Foo(Person a, Person b);
}

public class KungFoo : FooImpl
{
    public override bool Foo(Person a, Person b)
    {
        if (this.IsAmateur(a, b))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public class KongFoo : FooImpl
{
    public override bool Foo(Person a, Person b)
    {
        if (this.IsAmateur(a, b))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}

public abstract class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    public abstract bool Foo(Person a, Person b);

    protected readonly Func<Person, Person, bool> IsAmateur = (a, b) => a.IsAmateur || b.IsAmateur;
}

public class Person
{
    public bool IsAmateur { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Franky, I have something to go with now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a c# developer but I'd say you have to change the parent class to an actual class and implement the method inside it, of course if you want to add other unimplemented methods, you'd declare an abstract class, but this it what it would look like;

```
public abstract class IFoo{
   bool Foo(Person a, Person b){
      if (a.IsAmateur || b.IsAmateur) // common logic
         return true;
   }
   public abstract Object otherFooMethod(Object o);
}
```

and then in your child classes, you will use it like so:

```
public class KungFoo : IFoo{
   //Foo already implemented

   public Object otherFooMethod(Object o){
      return o;
   }

}

public class KongFoo : IFoo
{
   public bool Foo(Person a, Person b)
   {
       if (a.IsAmateur || b.IsAmateur) // common logic
         return false;
       return !base.Foo();
   }

   public Object otherFooMethod(Object o){
      return o;
   }
 }
```