# ArrayList Conceptual Issues

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist, console-application

I have tried to add 2 types of objects in an Array List and then have tried to display them but somehow it is not working. Do I need to use 2 Array List objects or how is it going to work?

Error Message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'ArrayList_Practice.Student' to type
>   'ArrayList_Practice.Employees'.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student st=null;
        Employees emp = null;
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Records");
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            st = new Student();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter roll");
            st.roll = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
            st.name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter course");
            st.course = Console.ReadLine();
            al.Add(st);

            emp = new Employees();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter empID");
            emp.empID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
            emp.name = Console.ReadLine();
            al.Add(emp);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("/////////////Show Records//////////");
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Roll "+((Student)al[i]).roll.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Name "+((Student)al[i]).name);
            Console.WriteLine("Course "+((Student)al[i]).course);

            Console.WriteLine("EmpID "+((Employees)al[i]).empID.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("EmpName "+((Employees)al[i]).name);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Student
{
    public int roll{ get; set;};
    public string name{ get; set;};
    public string course{ get; set;};
}

class Employees
{
    public int empID{ get; set;};
    public string name{ get; set;};
}
```

}

Comment: -1, not enough question marks.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Have added the error msg, take back the -1, will you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first element is a `Student`, and you are trying to cast it to `Employee` on first iteration in the loop.That's why you are getting an `InvalidCastException` in *run-time*.Don't use `ArrayLists`, use *strongly-typed* generic collections instead.For ex: [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to display *common* properties and you want to store `Students` and `Employees` into the same list, you can create a common `interface` for them and implement it.Then you can have a `List<CommonInterface>` and store your instances.But if you have different properties (it seems you have) you can't access them using common interface or base class,instead you can simply create an *extension* method and use `Reflection` to display all property values like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string DisplayPerson<T>(this T source)
    {
        if(source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
        var properties = source.GetType().GetProperties(flags);

        if (properties.Any())
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0} : {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(source));
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

}
```

Then just call it from the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(al[i].DisplayPerson());
}
```

Edit: Another way using common interface

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
}

class Student : IPerson
{
   /* implement the properties */
}

class Employees : IPerson
{
    /* implement the properties */
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<IPerson> personList = new List<IPerson>();

    personList.Add(new Student {/* set properties */});
    personList.Add(new Employee {/* set properties */});

    //  use a loop and display your properties without casting
}
```

Comment: If I supposedly use a List<T> what should be T in the above mentioned case?

Comment: @androidrill if you want to store `Employees` and `Student` in the same collection, then you can create a base class or common interface,declare your common properties inside of it.then implement it for `Student` and `Employee`, then create a `List<ICommonInterface>`

Comment: I was trying to store data from two classes in 1 Array List. As the concept says that an Array List is loosly typed and we can store pretty much anything into it, i tried experimenting with that concept. I was successful in storing one type of object and also displayed it. But when i tried to store 2 different types of objects into the same array list, i could not figure out a way to display it perfectly.

Comment: @androidrill did you try to method that I wrote ? that is a generic extension method and it can display any type of object.just try it.

Comment: To be honest with you, I am a student and not seasoned pro. I am still fiddling around Lists and other dicey concepts. I am much confused because the text says one thing but practically, when we get down to applying the same concept, it totally blasts off. Like in the above case. What do you suggest? If i want to keep the things simple, how should I be using List for this very problem.

Comment: @androidrill do you have different properties on Employee and Student? if you do, you can't use a common base class or interface.if you use still you need to cast your object and in order to do that you need to check for each type.if you have two type you need two checks, if three then three check and so on.. Your problem is, you can't cast a Student to Employee and also you can't do the opposite.Because they are not convertible to each other, there is no convertion defined from one type to other.

Comment: @androidrill If you want to use `List<T>` and you don't know how to implement a common interface, you can easily find examples on google, and this site.For ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343923/where-to-put-common-interface-methods-when-dealing-with-partial-classes-inherit just do some research

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, it would have been better if you could have shown me the correct way to implement a common interface as you currently know the problem and your answer would be appropriate. Atleast now I am sure that I can't store two objects of different types in an array list.

Comment: @androidrill no you can store anything into arraylist.your problem is displaying the properties and values.since you have different properties on different types you need to know the type and perform the cast as I said...

Comment: @androidrill also you should change your fields to properties in order to use the method I provide. because it get's the properties not the fields.or change GetProperties method to GetFields.

Comment: I have come to understand either i will have to use 2 lists. List<Student>L1=new List<Student>();  List<Employees>L2=new List<Employees>(); or use a common interface, which I don't know how to use. But I am still hazy about, how to implement a solution as to how to display 2 different objects using an array list.

Comment: I have changed the fields to properties.

Comment: @androidrill and did you use the extension method ?

Comment: that is working perfectly but is a little advanced for me to understand. I wish to ask you, if you could also give me a solution to implement employee and student properties via common interface.

Comment: @androidrill I have added it also.but remember, if you have different properties, you can't use common interface.because still you have to check for type and cast it in order to access properties of specific type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and what is the exact meaning of different properties which you have mentioned time and again? There are fields for Student's ID,Name&Course and there are fields for Employee's ID,Name. But the Data for student and employees is going to be different.

Comment: @androidrill I meant that exactly.You have different fields and properties.That's why I provide you a solution using Reflection first.When you use List<IPerson> you can only access the properties and methods that declared by this interface.for ex. if you declare a different property on Employee that doesn't exists in IPerson, you can't display it.you have to cast that object to Employee first.

Comment: you are absolutely right sir. I have studied the answer and possibly, gained a lot from our conversation. Thanks for your help, it really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

in your array list, your 0th element is a student type and 1st element is an employee type.

in your loop, then you're trying to cast your 0th element to an employee to display empID.
hence you need to be aware of this..

you need to do proper cast check for the loop to work.
check if the element is student or employee and display accordingly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
{
 var student = al[i] as Student;

 if (student != null)
 {
        Console.WriteLine("Roll "+ student.roll.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Name "+ student.name);
        Console.WriteLine("Course "+ student.course);
 }
 else
 {
  var employee  = al[i] as Employee;

  if (employee  != null)
  {
        Console.WriteLine("EmpID "+ employee.empID.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("EmpName "+ employee.name);
  }
 }
}
```

though this works for your problem, in general you should be using strongly types collections.
e.g. `List<Student>` and `List<Employee>`

Comment: "Without a Loop" solution that you have mentioned above doesn't work. It would display only 1 set of records for students and employees. If you wish to enter more than 1 record, it just displays the first set of records that you have entered.

Answer (score 0):

You need two lists, because you are trying to store two different types of objects in the array. While it's possible to manage this, you'd be better off keeping it simple: have an array for students and an array for employees.

I'm not sure why you enter the student and employee records at the same time, in pairs. Are the employees connected to the students in some way? Are the students employees? If so, you'd be better off creating a single object that represents student-employee, or whatever the relationship is, and filling a single list with items of that type.

Also, it's 2014 and you shouldn't be using `ArrayList`. At the very least, use `List<>`.